# FFmpeg can't convert mov with alpha channel to webm with alpha channel

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion

I am trying to convert a mov with alpha channel to a webm with alpha channel by ffmpeg. However, what I got was the webm video **without alpha channel**.  My methods are based on those link:

- [Alpha transparency in Chrome video by Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video)
- [Convert mov with Alpha to VP9 Webm with Alpha Using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856236/convert-mov-with-alpha-to-vp9-webm-with-alpha-using-ffmpeg)

The code I used:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx-vp9 output.webm
```

And the output here:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'overlap_1.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2019-01-17T08:43:07.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:04.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 34346 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), bgra(progressive), 1080x1080, 32249 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-17T08:43:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Animation
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-17T08:43:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
File 'overlap_C1.webm' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (qtrle (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7ffdb8018200] v1.7.0
Output #0, webm, to 'overlap_C1.webm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (libvpx-vp9), yuva420p, 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 24 fps, 1k tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-17T08:43:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   96 fps=1.6 q=0.0 Lsize=     145kB time=00:00:03.95 bitrate= 299.9kbits/s speed=0.0649x    
video:70kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 106.879829%
```

According to the output, we know that：

- video codec：vp9
- pixel format：yuva420p
- file format：webm

It looked OK but when I tried to play this video by IINA(a great video player)and Chrome then the video showed the black color instead of the alpha channel. **No Alpha Channel!**

And I tried the codec vp8 then I got the same effect webm video.I don't know what the hell happened on me. This is my situation：

- system: macOS mojave 10.14.2
- libvpx: enable
- xcode: installed

Hope someone can give me advice, thanks!

Comment: And you have verified that other WebM/VP9 videos with alpha channel play fine in Chrome?

Comment: oh, I didn't expect to verify this! I have tried something and I found that it is ok! Thanks to remind me that! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you got it solved!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question **has been solved**. I made a mistake on confirming whether the webm video has the alpha channel. This is the result I played mov with alpha channel and webm with alpha channel with 2 softwares.

**IINA** (the video player stared 17034 on Github)

- mov: background with black and white squares
- webm: background with black color

**Chrome** (version71, stable）

- mov: nonsupport
- webm: background with black color

This far, the black background had made me think the webm video doesn't have the alpha channel.

Then I found the [website](https://simpl.info/videoalpha/) display how Chrome supports the webm video with alpha channel. The super interesting thing is that I can change the webm video background color, then I checked the html code, they used the CSS to control the background color.How a great way to confirm whether the webm video has alpha channel!

So I did this steps to confirm my webm video:

1. open the webm video with Chrome
2. enter developer tool
3. add the CSS code to the video tag

   style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0)"
4. if the webm video has the alpha channel, the video background will change to **GREEN**, or it won't happen anything. And lucky my webm video has the alpha channel!

Thanks, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Blender 3D open source software's video sequence editor can take a video file and export a Webm file. Blender uses FFmpeg. See [www.blender.org](http://www.blender.org)